# Save serialize image in database in custom format

Tags: php, html

We work on web services, we want save the image database in formate 
a:1:{i:0;s:1:"a.jpg,b.jpg,c.jpg";} But our image save as
 a:3:{i:0;s:7:"am1.jpg";i:1;s:7:"am2.jpg";i:2;s:7:"am3.jpg";} . Please help me

Our code is:

```
<?php
```

include_once('connection.php');

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

$json = json_decode($data);

$target_path = "uploads/";

```
$target_path1 = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image1']['name']);
$target_path2 = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image2']['name']);
$target_path3 = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image3']['name']);

$file_upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $target_path1);
$file_upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'], $target_path2);
$file_upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'], $target_path3);    

$image = serialize(array($_FILES['image1']['name'], $_FILES['image2']['name'], $_FILES['image3']['name']));      

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`image`) VALUES ('$image')";
        $qur = mysql_query($sql);
```

echo json_encode($response);

?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = serialize(array($_FILES['image1']['name'] .','. $_FILES['image2']['name'] .','. $_FILES['image3']['name']));
```

or

```
$image = serialize(array(implode(',', array_column($_FILES,'name'))));
```

Though why bother with an array if all you want is a comma separated string

Answer (score 0):

You can implode image names and then serialize the string.

```
$image = serialize(implode(',', array($_FILES['image1']['name'], $_FILES['image2']['name'], $_FILES['image3']['name'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the strings in an array:

```
$a = array();
$a[] = 'am1.jpg';
$a[] = 'am2.jpg';
$a[] = 'am3.jpg';
```

And then implode it:

```
$files = implode( ',', $a );
```

To achieve exactly what you want it should be:

```
echo json_encode( array( $files ) );
```